# Exercise with field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

In a field with characteristic other than 2, if we have two elements in our field, $a,b \in F$ such that $F(\sqrt{a})= F(\sqrt{b})$ and $[F(\sqrt{a}):F]=[F(\sqrt{b}):F]=2$

Then we can deduce that $ab \in F^2$

I am not sure how to do this. How do we know that  $ab \in F^2$ ? Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $F(\sqrt{a})=F(\sqrt{b})$ and both are of degree $2$, then we can express $\sqrt{a}$ as $\sqrt{a}=r+s\sqrt{b}$ for some $s,b\in{F}$. Squaring both sides we get
$$a = r^2 + s^2b + 2rs\sqrt{b}.$$
That means that $2rs=0$, and since the characteristic is not $2$, then $rs=0$, so $r=0$ or $s=0$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I can take it partly from there. If r=0 then a=bs^2 so then ab=(sb)^2, and we are done, right?

Comment: I am less sure about the s=0 case.

Comment: @EricJames: That would mean $a=r^2$, but then $\sqrt{a}=\pm r\in F$. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the help!